# Page Redirection in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am having a check box in Home Page "<%=Html.CheckBox("Sample","1")%>Sample" I am having 3 Tabs in my Application (Home,About,Product). When i check the check box,i should be redirected to the Product Page. How to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about his:

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm("Redirect", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "chksSubmit" })) %>
<%{ %>
        <%: Html.CheckBox("CheckNow", new { onclick = "javascript:document.getElementById('chksSubmit').submit();" })%>
<% }%>
```

In the controller:

```
 public ActionResult Redirect()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Home");
    }
```

Comment: Its working fine..Here where you had mention the Checkbox Text..( i.e. ChkYes or ChkNo 0 )

Comment: <%: Html.CheckBox("CheckNow", new { onclick = "javascript:document.getElementById('chksSubmit1').submit();" })%> <label>Back to Home Page</label>

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
<%=Html.CheckBox("Sample","1", new {onclick="location='"+Url.Action("Product")+"'")%>
```

Comment: I cant able to get the onClick property..." <%=Html.CheckBox("Sample","1",(onClick ="location='"+Url.Action("Product")+"'")%>"

Comment: You missed out the *new {* statement.

Comment: <%= Html.CheckBox("Sample", "1", new { onClick = "location='" + Url.Action("Product") + "'" })%> ..... This is also showing error..